# $\mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$ contains a copy of every countable ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to understand [this proof of the existence of an uncountable ordinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/395461/49908). I don't see why $\mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$ contains a copy of every countable ordinal as it is said.

For example, what element of $\mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$ would correspond to $\omega\cdot 2$ ?

Comment: $\omega$2 denotes what here?

Comment: @Paul: The second limit ordinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Denoting it by $\omega+\omega$ may be more clear.

Comment: @Paul : The reason for this notation is that it could be generalized more easily. For instance $\omega 4 := \omega + \omega + \omega + \omega$.

Comment: @M.G: It would be confused with $\omega_2$.

Comment: @Paul: In order to be more precise I should write $\omega\cdot 2$ but except from that, this notation seems quite standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a countable ordinal, and let $f\colon\omega\to\alpha$ be a bijection. Then the relation $\{\langle m,n\rangle\mid f(m)\in f(n)\}$ is a well-ordering of $\omega$ with order type $\alpha$ (with $f$ being the isomorphism), and it is an element of $\mathcal P(\omega\times\omega)$.

If you want a particular relation which is isomorphic to $\omega\cdot2$, take the following: $$\{\langle m,n\rangle\mid (m<n\text{ and }m\equiv n\pmod 2)\lor m\text{ is odd, and }n\text{ is even}\}.$$

Comment: If I got it right, a relation on $\omega$ can be coded by a collection of ordered pairs of elements natural numbers. In particular, any well-order on subsets of $\omega$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$.

Comment: @M.G: No, a relation on a set $A$ **is** a subset of $A\times A$. So a well-order of $\omega$ is a set of pairs of natural numbers, that is to say, an element of $\mathcal P(\omega\times\omega)$.